# Missing required parameters for [Route: sender] [URI: {name}/{code}] [Missing parameters: name, code]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

This may seem duplicate but I have this problem using AJAX and I don't know how to fix it.

**Routes: web.php**

```
Route::get('/{name}/{code}', 'TestController@counter');
Route::post('/{name}/{code}', 'TestController@sender')->name('sender');
```

**Controller: TestController.php**

```
public function counter() {
    return view('room');
}

public function sender(Request $request) {
    $xd = array(
        '1' => request('text'), 
        '2' => Request::url()
    );
    event(new TestEvent($xd));
}
```

**View: room.blade.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                @csrf
                <label for="lname">Code:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="text" name="text"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
                var data = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    URL: "{{ route('sender') }}",
                    data: data,
                    success: function () {
                        console.log("works");
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error is the AJAX  if I take it out I don't get an error. The AJAX code is to call the Controller without redirecting to another page. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Remove `'/{name}/{code}'` from your routes.

Comment: I need them its not a fixed route. Sometimes its /hello/123 other times its /hello/345

Comment: you are not sending the parameters...

Comment: How do I send them? What do I need to change?

Comment: Send in this way : `URL: "/"+ name +"/" + code",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Route:

**Routes: web.php**

```
Route::get('', 'TestController@counter');
Route::post('', 'TestController@sender')->name('sender');
```

If you want to send a parameter, then define your parameter in your route, like below:

**Routes: web.php**

```
Route::get('/{name}/{code}', 'TestController@counter');
Route::post('/{name}/{code}', 'TestController@sender')->name('sender');
```

**Controller: TestController.php**

```
public function counter($name, $code) {
    //---Note: Use $name and $code in your method
    return view('room', compact('name', $code));
}

public function sender(Request $request, $name, $code) {
    //---Note: Use Those parameters in your method
    $xd = array(
        '1' => request('text'), 
        '2' => Request::url()
    );
    event(new TestEvent($xd));
}
```

**View: room.blade.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                @csrf
                <label for="lname">Code:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="text" name="text">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
                var data = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    URL: "{{ route('sender', ['name' => '', 'code' => '']) }}",
                    data: data,
                    success: function () {
                        console.log("works");
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need dynamic routes. Sometimes its /hello/123 and other times /helloo/321

Comment: Now I get:  compact(): Undefined variable: ABCD23                                                     
in the url:http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ABCD23

Comment: I should also add that im using laravel 8. I dont know if maybe it modifies this  "{{ route('sender', ['name' => '', 'code' => '']) }}",

Comment: run "composer update" as in the latest Laravel this issue has been resolved.

Comment: Ok fixed it with your help but changed something

Comment: Got this error now: 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ ABCD23:137
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2     Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Inside your ajax you can define your URL like this: url:"/"+name+"/"+code,